# Effectively and repeatedly updating DOM with data without breaking page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, single-page-application

I'm creating a SPA which of course uses AJAX to dynamically load pages in a div. My layout is a side accordion menu where when you click on an item, it loads information on a div next to it. My problem is that if a person decides to click menu items as fast as they can per second, I start getting blank content in my pages. So my question is, what are some best practices (if any) to avoid pages breaking when you have people clicking so fast?

Things I'm doing for performance:

- Using html templates and json files to build pages before application starts, keeping the (simple) pages in memory to grab - instead of calling ajax every click
- For now, on each click I'm using at `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout` set to some milliseconds to slow down the process of switching pages - not ideal

Unfortunately, I can't post code because it's too long, but I'm hoping I can get some help with this information.

Thanks guys!

**Note: This is only front-end work, no databases because the load isn't heavy.

**EDIT:**
Here is a little snippet of my setTimeout and clearTimeout:

    `if (clickTimeout) { clearTimeout(clickTimeout); }
    clickTimeout = setTimeout(function()
    {
        clickLink(menuItem.attr('href'));
    }, 500);`

Comment: Are you aborting the previous ajax request when the second request is kicked off?

Comment: That's the weird thing. I'm only doing ajax calls (synchronous) only when the app starts and am saving the info in arrays. Then for each click, I'm going to the arrays for content, not calling ajax again. It seems faster but I'm still having that problem.

Comment: So your page data is being stored locally in Javascript arrays?

Comment: Right. Because it's not heavy data, I figured it would be better than to call ajax every time.

Comment: I personally don't see any issues with `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout`, provided they are implemented effectively...

Comment: @ne1410s I added my setTimeout code above. Would this be effective? It's pretty simple. I added this in my click event.

Comment: Seems fine to me - Maybe you could also add an `else` clause to allow those innocent 1-clickers to pass through without delay?

Comment: Worth a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I usually just disable the UI element that caused the event before sending the ajax, and then the client side code re-enables it after the data has arrived. This of course can only be done if you have code that runs when the data arrives. You might also be making mistakes when updating the DOM with the data if that is how you display it. Sometimes blank DIVs only appear after a while.

I think the title of the question is wrong and should be more along the lines of effectively repeatedly updating the DOM with data without breaking the page.

Comment: Thanks, I never thought about that. I'm changing the title now.